# google dfp image links broken

Tags: google-dfp, google-web-designer

I have built a creative in Google Web Designer and published.

In the zip file that is outputted, I have one html5 file and one png file (our logo).

When I preview in GWD (Google Web Designer), I am able to see our logo in the creative.

When I upload the zip file to DFP Testing Area, into the creatives section, everything uploads correctly.

When I preview the creative, the link to our logo shows up as a broken link.

https://partner.googleadservices.com/gampad/our_logo.png

Does the testing area of DFP SB (Double Click for Publishers Small Business) allow images to be part of creative?

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem...

DFP SM don't allow yout to upload GWD Zip directly.

Instead, you need to use DoubleClick Studio or (as a workaround) convert all images to base64 and embed them.

I made a tool to do that, but I don't have it published.

If you are interested, email me..